# Какие пакеты можно использовать без явного import'а?

Tags: java

Допустим, вы пишете класс `Example` в пакете `org.stepic.java.example`. Классы из каких пакетов вы можете использовать в классе `Example` по их коротким именам без явного import'а?

Варианты ответов:

1. пакет по умолчанию
2. `org.stepic.java.example`
3. все подпакеты `org.stepic.java.example`
4. `java.lang`
5. `java.util`

Я не понимаю что от меня хотят то ли есть package то ли его нет совсем.

Comment: оффтоп: вы же видите в каком виде в итоге нарисован вопрос (например: что в одну линию список, а не в столбец). Вы же можете его сделать более читабельным и подрефаторить, правда? Инструменты для этого вполне имеются

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос-опросник и является оффтопом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию импортируется текущий пакет и `java.lang`

Answer (score 2):

Ответ будет следующим:

- `org.stepic.java.example`
- `java.lang`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пришли с Ulearn java то ответы:

com.example.java

java.lang